# String concatenation without allocation in java

Tags: java, string, memory, concatenation, allocation

Is there a way to concatenate two Strings (not final) without allocating memory?

For example, I have these two Strings:

```
final String SCORE_TEXT = "SCORE: ";
String score = "1000"; //or int score = 1000;
```

When I concatenate these two strings, a new `String` object is created.

```
font.drawMultiLine(batch, SCORE_TEXT + score, 50f, 670f);//this creates new string each time
```

Since this is done in the main game loop (executed ~60 times in one second), there are a lot of allocations.

Can I somehow do this without allocation?

Comment: Does this actually cause a performance problem, or are you doing [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)?

Comment: Yes it actually causes performance problems, because of the gc. Game is for mobile devices, and on slower devices, gc causes fps drops...

Comment: @Kenneth Clark, String format creates a few new objects. eg. `Formatter`, `Pattern`...

Comment: string builder or buffer , o just write directly without concat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious solution is to not recreate the output `String` on every frame, but only when it changes.

One way to do this is to store it somewhere outside your main loop and update it when a certain event happens, i.e. the "score" actually changes. In your main loop you then just use that pre-created `String`.

If you can't/or don't want to have this event based approach, you can always store the "previous" score and only concatenate a new String when the previous score is different from the current score.

Depending on how often your score actually changes, this should cut out most reallocations. Unless of course the score changes at 60 fps, in which case this whole point is completely mute because nobody would be able to read the text you're printing.

Comment: this is actually the best suggestion so far. But i think that even better idea is to draw each string separately. I will have one more draw call, but i think its much better than a lot of allocations

Comment: @pedja You could do that too, but you'd probably have to manually align the two strings then, which may be feasible in your case because the first string is static.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't understand the question the first time around. Have you tried using the following?

```
SCORE_TEXT.concat(score);
```

Comment: `sb.toString();` creates new String

Comment: use the `res` object which is already instantiated instead of concatening on the fly

Comment: score is not static string, it is dynamically created

Comment: @nuno, it's absolutely the same as writing `String res = SCORE_TEXT+score`: the javac compiler generates effectively the same bytecode.

Comment: Didn't understand the question the first time around - edited

Answer (score 1):

[Seems that](http://libgdx-users.googlecode.com/git-history/ffe2f24c071c9125c99a3e3169ce856e8c3c4be6/gdx-shared-libs/libs/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#drawMultiLine%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20float,%20float%29) `drawMultiLine` accepts not a `String`, but `CharSequence`. Thus you may probably implement your own `CharSequence` which does not actually concatenates two strings. Here's the draft implementation:

```
public class ConcatenatedString implements CharSequence {
    final String left, right;
    final int leftLength;

    public ConcatenatedString(String left, String right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.leftLength = left.length();
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return leftLength+right.length();
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return index < leftLength ? left.charAt(index) : right.charAt(index-leftLength);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        if(end <= leftLength)
            return left.substring(start, end);
        if(start >= leftLength)
            return right.substring(start-leftLength, end-leftLength);
        return toString().substring(start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return left.concat(right);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
font.drawMultiLine(batch, new ConcatenatedString(SCORE_TEXT, score), 50f, 670f);
```

Internally in your case `drawMultiline` just needs the `length` and `charAt` methods. Using `ConcatenatedString` you create only one new object. In contrast when you use `SCORE_TEXT + score`, you create a temporary `StringBuilder` which creates internally `char[]` array, copies the input symbols, resizes the array if necessary, then creates the final `String` object which creates the new `char[]` array and copies the symbols again. Thus it's likely that `ConcatenatedString` will be faster.

Comment: Only if `toString` or `subSequence` is called. But it's unlikely in your case.

Comment: but wait, what about `new ConcatenatedString`, this is creating new object also?

Comment: It's only one new object. When you use `SCORE_TEXT+score`, you create at least four objects (maybe more) and copy symbol arrays.

Comment: i didn't know that, i thought that it only creates only one new object, i guess ill have to do some more reading about string concatenation...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can populate a value without allocation a memory for it.. what best you can do is create a global string variable and provide the value of SCORE_TEXT + score to it. Use that global string variable in font.drawMultiLine() method.

This way you can minimize the amount of memeory allocated as memory is allocated only once and the same location is updated again & again.

Comment: What you suggest is impossible because score is dynamic string

Answer (score 0):

String is designed to be immutable in Java. use StringBuilder